# What does None in cv2.resize mean?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, resize, opencv3.0

I came across the following snippet used to resize an image:

```
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx = 1/3, fy = 1/3)
```

What is the call actually doing? Why is the output size parameter set to `None`? When I tried to run this snippet with `OpenCV 3.4.3`, it gives an error but works fine with `OpenCV 3.4.2`.

I want to emulate this behavior in `OpenCV 3.4.3`. What is it doing and how I could do it?

Comment: Can you give a trackback of the actual error you are getting?

Comment: What is the error you get in OpenCV 3.4.3? Also, which version of python are you using in both cases?

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV function `resize` has 2 different modes for resizing the image.

1. A fixed output size can be specified in the 2nd parameter.
2. Scaling factor for each dimension can be specified using the `fx` and `fy` parameters which are used for calculating the output size.

If both methods are used simultaneously, then `fx` and `fy` parameters are ignored. The output size parameter is mandatory for both cases. It means that if we want to use the scaling method, we have to pass `None` in place of the output size parameter. `None` indicates that we do not want to use this parameter.

## Example Usage:

#### Fixed output size:

```
img = cv2.resize( img, (640, 480) )
```

#### Dynamic output size:

```
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx = 1.0/3.0, fy = 1.0/3.0)
```

Comment: So in the dynamic output size, the width of the image would be multiplied by 1/3 and height by 1/3?

Comment: @Amanda... Please accept the answer if it solves your problem so that the question can get off the un-answered list.